# Samba: how do have one username to a number of linux users

Tags: samba

I have a samba server installed on a Linux box.  It runs well with me loging in as "user" and accessing my "Home" directory but I would also alike to access the files owned by "www-data".  Is there away to login as "user" but for that to be mapped to "www-data"?

Comment: what is the group on those files, and does it have the permissions you want? You can have multiple users in a group, but only one user can be the owner of a file

Comment: Its been a long time since I played with Samba, but if I remember correctly if you have two different shares and you can configure one of them to squash all writes to a particular user, so you can access both shares at the same time - on one you will be yourself on the other you will be www-data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by modifying your Samba configuration file (typically found at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`). In the share definition that you want to access with 'www-data' permissions, you can add the `force user` directive. Here’s an example:

```ini
[www-data-share]
   path = /path/to/www-data/directory
   writable = yes
   force user = www-data
   valid users = user
```

With this configuration, whenever 'user' accesses the `www-data-share` share, they will have the permissions of the 'www-data' user.

Remember to replace `/path/to/www-data/directory` with the actual path to your 'www-data' directory and restart the Samba service after making these changes for them to take effect.

```bash
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

**Note:** Ensure that the 'user' has the necessary file system permissions to access the 'www-data' directory as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I was looking for.